# Tensor calculus: problem with second order delta systems property

Tags: tensors, kronecker-delta

The properties described in this question come from P. Grinfeld's book: "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces".

The Kronecker delta (or symbol) is defined by equation (4.73) as:
$$
\delta^i_j=\left\{\begin{array}{r}
1,\forall i=j\\
0,\forall i\neq j.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Later, in chapter 9, equation (9.27), the second order delta system $\delta^{ij}_{rs}$ is defined as a determinant:
$$
\delta^{ij}_{rs} = \begin{vmatrix}
\delta^i_r & \delta^i_s\\
\delta^j_r & \delta^j_s
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Note that prior to this definition, an important remark is given: *A particular entry of a delta system has value $1$ when the upper and lower are identical sets of distinct numbers related by an even permutation, $-1$ if the sets are related by an odd permutation, and $0$ otherwise.*

Therefore, the object $\delta^{ij}_{rs}$ is skew-symmetric in its lower or upper indices, meaning that $\delta^{ij}_{sr}=-\delta^{ij}_{rs} = -\delta^{ji}_{sr} = \delta^{ji}_{rs}$.

My issue is with the contraction property with indices that appear twice, once as upper, and once as lower. For this, equation (9.22) states that:
$$
\delta^{ij}_{rj}=2\delta^i_r.
$$

**However**, taking the previous definition with the determinant operation,

$$
\delta^{ij}_{rj} = \begin{vmatrix}
\delta^i_r & \delta^i_j\\
\delta^j_r & \delta^j_j
\end{vmatrix} = \delta^i_r\delta^j_j - \delta^i_j\delta^j_r.
$$

But according to the Kronecker delta definition above, $\delta^j_j=1$. Additionally, by contraction, the second term of the right hand side above becomes $\delta^i_j\delta^j_r = \delta^i_r$. Therefore,
$$
\delta^{ij}_{rj} =\delta^i_r-\delta^i_r=0.
$$

What am I doing wrong here? Is there some property that I am still missing in order to retrieve equation (9.22)?

Comment: Are you considering only three dimensions by any chance? If so, note that $\delta^i_r\delta^j_j = 3\delta^i_r$, where the Einstein sum convention is used, i.e. $\delta^j_j = \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta^j_j = 3$.

Comment: @P-A Well, this just voids my question... I was taking $\delta^j_j$ to be equal to 1 this whole time, but indeed, summation convention is in fact triggered by the double appearance of $j$ index above and below. Otherwise, yes, I forgot to mention that 3 dimensions are implied.